# Convert HTML to a Word-document which can be edited in Word Online

Tags: ms-word, office365, docx, onedrive

Our users write in a rich-text field, pretty much like this one, and we would like for them to be able to export this as a Word Document in their OneDrive, preserving the formatting, and being able to open the file in Word Online.

I have no trouble creating new files using the https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/ api. The problem is the conversion to docx. The google api provides this conversion automatically, but I did not find that for Microsoft. I tried using html-docx-js and it **almost** works perfectly.

The file is created:

[image]

However when opening the file the following dialog pops up:
[image]

Opening in read-only mode works, the file shows with the correct formatting.
Downloading the file and opening in desktop word works perfectly (i.e. editing as well).

The HTML-content i use is a simple div with a few p-tags, so the "Objects that Word Online doesn't support" probably comes from html-docx-js.

Here's an example word-file that is created. This file can be opened as normal in desktop Word but only opened in read-only in Word Online
https://1drv.ms/w/s!AqpUGtnMiyurgwE543OscH7PdLnY

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share the document that you're generating ? It is almost impossible to help without enough information

Comment: @edi9999 Absolutely, I've added a word file now.

Comment: Ok, I see, the reason is that the "alt-chunk" feature is not available in Office Onlie.

Comment: I personally support a HTML to docx converter (https://docxtemplater.com/modules/html/) but it is a paid npm module, probably not of value if what you want is just to convert `<p>` and `<div>`